# Error in IE11: SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

This code is working fine with all browsers except IE11. I'm getting console error as "SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action" at 2nd line **var component = new Constr(_.omit(node, 'children'));** Please advise what changes need to be done here

```
function initComponent(node, Constr) {
        var component = new Constr(_.omit(node, 'children'));

        consoleLogger.info('componentStartInitialization', {
            component: node.component,
            componentName: node.name
        });

        registry.set(node.name, component);
    }
```

Comment: What is `Constr`?

Comment: It's a function

Comment: But how is it defined? It seems it's not constructable, which suggests it's an arrow function as they cannot be called with `new`. However, you say that it *works* in IE11 which is strange since an arrow function should throw a syntax error there - IE11 doesn't recognise (most) of the ES6+ syntax.

Comment: And what is `_`? Does it refer to *lodash* or *underscore.js*, or is it something else?

Comment: @FZs it refers to underscore.js